# I am trying to update data on Thingspeak,but it updates only at once using Edison

Tags: iot, intel-edison, smartthings

I am trying to update Thingspeak using Edison, it updates Data but only once.

Here is my code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// ThingSpeak Settings
char thingSpeakAddress[] = "api.thingspeak.com";  //TS

String writeAPIKey = "**************";    //TS
const int updateThingSpeakInterval = 10 * 1000;      // Time interval in milliseconds to update ThingSpeak (number of seconds * 1000 = interval)

char ssid[] = "*******";     //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "********";  // your network password


int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the Wifi radio's status

// initialize the library instance:
WiFiClient client;
String stringVal = ""; 
// Variable Setup
long lastConnectionTime = 0; 
boolean lastConnected = false;
int failedCounter = 0;
int a;
//char dtostrfbuffer[20];

float tempC;
float temp =3;
void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
 // printWifiStatus();
  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
    // don't continue:
    while(true);
  } 

 // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);

  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data:
  Serial.print("You're connected to the network");
  // printCurrentNet();
  // printWifiData();

}

  void loop() {

 a = analogRead(temp);
 tempC = (5.0 * a * 1000)/1024.0;
 float cel = tempC/10;

 // converts temp  to string

 stringVal += String(int(cel))+ "."+String(getDecimal(cel));

 //char buf[16];
 //String strTemp = floatToString(16 , cel , 5);
 //Serial.println(strTemp);

 // Print Update Response to Serial Monitor
  if (client.available())
  {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // Disconnect from ThingSpeak
  if (!client.connected() && lastConnected)
  {
    Serial.println("...disconnected");
    Serial.println();

    client.stop();  }

  // Update ThingSpeak
  if(!client.connected() && (millis() - lastConnectionTime > updateThingSpeakInterval))
  {
    updateThingSpeak("field1="+ stringVal);
     Serial.print( stringVal);

     Serial.println("C");
     delay(1000);
     Serial.println();

  }

  lastConnected = client.connected();

}
//function to extract decimal part of float
long getDecimal(float val)
{
 int intPart = int(val);
 long decPart = 100*(val-intPart); //I am multiplying by 100 assuming that the foat values will have a maximum of 3 decimal places
                                   //Change to match the number of decimal places you need
 if(decPart>0)return(decPart);           //return the decimal part of float number if it is available 
 else if(decPart<0)return((-1)*decPart); //if negative, multiply by -1
 else if(decPart=0)return(00);           //return 0 if decimal part of float number is not available
}

void updateThingSpeak(String  stringVal)
{
  if (client.connect(thingSpeakAddress, 80))
  {         
    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: "+writeAPIKey+"\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print( stringVal.length());
    client.print("\n\n");

    client.print( stringVal);

    lastConnectionTime = millis();

    if (client.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("Connecting to ThingSpeak...");
      Serial.println();

      failedCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      failedCounter++;

      Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak failed ("+String(failedCounter, DEC)+")");   
      Serial.println();
    }

  }
  else
  {
    failedCounter++;

    Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak Failed ("+String(failedCounter, DEC)+")");   
    Serial.println();

    lastConnectionTime = millis(); 
  }
}
```

Why does it update Data only once?

Comment: Instead of linking to an external source for your code, [edit] your question to include the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually it is my question why it only updates only once

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue using the Edison and I fixed the example github code by changing:

```
if (!client.connected() && lastConnected)
```

to this: (no more '!')

```
if (client.connected() && lastConnected)
```

I found the whole sample to be very oddly designed and I tweaked it a lot.
I have a working example and an article [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/internet-of-things-a-plant-monitor-on-the-intel-edison-board)